# How do I convert a DateTime into a BIGINT in Stream Analytics?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to convert a DateTime (from System.Timestamp()) into a BIGINT or the string equivalent in Azure Stream Analytics. Unfortunately, the obvious method does not work:

`CAST(System.Timestamp() AS BIGINT)`

I just get the error:

> Cannot cast value of type 'datetime' to type 'bigint' in expression 'CAST (System . Timestamp ( ) AS BIGINT)'.

My end goal is to just get either the ticks equivalent of the timestamp or some sort of formatted output such as yyyyMMddHHmmss that I want to use as a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`DATEDIFF`** function, with a difference in **`microseconds`** to obtain unique values.

The following code provides a timestamp equivalent to ticks:

```
DATEDIFF(microsecond, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z', System.Timestamp()) AS TicksEquivalent
```

Output:

[image]